# Multiple joins on same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2005

I have two table:

**tbl_EmploymentSegmentEM:**

```
╔══════╦═════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ SrNo ║ CIBILTuefID ║ Prospectno ║ ApplicantType ║         ApplicantName         ║ SegmentTag ║ AccountType ║ DateReportedandCertified ║ OccupationCode ║
╠══════╬═════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║    1 ║           1 ║     718580 ║ APPLICANT     ║ RAJKUMAR GIRISHCHANDRA PANDEY ║ E01        ║          10 ║                 31122014 ║             02 ║
║    2 ║           4 ║     718638 ║ APPLICANT     ║ Anil Kumar Aggarwal           ║ E01        ║          10 ║                 31122014 ║             01 ║
╚══════╩═════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

**tbl_CIBILFieldDescription:**

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║ Header ║ FieldTag ║          FieldName           ║ Value ║      ValueDescription       ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ PT     ║       03 ║ TelephoneType                ║ 03    ║ Office Phone                ║
║ EM     ║       03 ║ OccupationCode               ║ 01    ║ Salaried                    ║
║ EM     ║       03 ║ OccupationCode               ║ 02    ║ Self Employed Professional. ║
║ EM     ║       03 ║ OccupationCode               ║ 03    ║ Self Employed               ║
║ EM     ║       03 ║ OccupationCode               ║ 04    ║ Others                      ║
║ EM     ║       05 ║ NetGrossIncomeIndicator      ║ G     ║ Gross Income                ║
║ EM     ║       05 ║ NetGrossIncomeIndicator      ║ N     ║ Net Income                  ║
║ EM     ║       06 ║ MonthlyAnnualIncomeIndicator ║ M     ║ Net Monthly                 ║
║ EM     ║       06 ║ MonthlyAnnualIncomeIndicator ║ A     ║ Net Annual                  ║
║ SC     ║       01 ║ ScoreCardName                ║ 01    ║ CIBILTUSCR                  ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

I am trying to get Account Type and Occupation code description from  `tbl_CIBILFieldDescription` for the corresponding values.

I tried this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CIBILTuefID, 
                Prospectno, 
                ApplicantType, 
                ApplicantName, 
                SegmentTag, 
                AccountType, 
                DateReportedandCertified, 
                OccupationCode, 
                mst.ValueDescription  AS OccupationCodeDesc, 
                Income, 
                NetGrossIncomeIndicator, 
                mst.ValueDescription AS NetGrossIncomeIndicatorDesc, 
                MonthlyAnnualIncomeIndicator, 
                DateofEntryforErrorCode, 
                ErrorCode, 
                DateofEntryforCIBILRemarksCode, 
                CIBILRemarksCode, 
                DateofEntryforErrorDisputeRemarksCode, 
                ErrorDisputeRemarksCode1, 
                ErrorDisputeRemarksCode2, 
                MkrId, 
                MkdDt 
FROM   tbl_EmploymentSegmentEM EM 
INNER JOIN tbl_CIBILFieldDescription mst 
    ON 1 = 1 
WHERE mst.Header = 'EM' 
  AND mst.FieldName = 'OccupationCode' 
  AND mst.Value = EM.OccupationCode
```

And it seems to work ok for `OccupationCode` but what if I want both `OccupationCode` and `AccountType` from the same query? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `INNER JOIN.... ON 1 = 1` please explain what this join is attempting to achieve.

Comment: That's a cross join, i.e. similar to an old style join having the join conditions specified in the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your table multiple times using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cibiltuefid, 
                prospectno, 
                applicanttype, 
                applicantname, 
                segmenttag, 
                accounttype, 
                datereportedandcertified, 
                occupationcode, 
                mst.valuedescription  AS OccupationCodeDesc, 
                income, 
                netgrossincomeindicator, 
                mst1.valuedescription AS NetGrossIncomeIndicatorDesc, 
                monthlyannualincomeindicator, 
                dateofentryforerrorcode, 
                errorcode, 
                dateofentryforcibilremarkscode, 
                cibilremarkscode, 
                dateofentryforerrordisputeremarkscode, 
                errordisputeremarkscode1, 
                errordisputeremarkscode2, 
                mkrid, 
                mkddt 
                ,mst.ValueDescription AS Occupation
                ,mst1.ValueDescription AS Account
FROM tbl_employmentsegmentem EM
LEFT JOIN tbl_cibilfielddescription mst 
    ON mst.fieldname = 'OccupationCode' 
    AND mst.value = EM.occupationcode 
    AND mst.header = 'EM'
LEFT JOIN tbl_cibilfielddescription mst1 
    ON mst1.fieldname = 'AccountType' 
    AND mst1.value = EM.accounttype
    AND mst1.header = 'EM'
```

Comment: I was doing the exact same thing except for left join instead of inner. Thanks, will mark answer.